# How to get next point in Highcharts tooltip

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, series, point

how can I access to the next point of the series from the tooltip formatter.
Because I want to do a sum between both points.
Like this.y + next.y.

But I don't know how to have an access to the next point.

Answer (score 3):

This need to be done in a few steps:

- get x-index according to x-value: `var index = this.series.xData.indexOf(this.x);`
- now get y-value: `var nextY = this.series.yData[index+1];`

And all you need to do is to sum values, like this: `var sum = this.y + nextY;`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I try to do this. I have 2 errors in my log:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xData' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xData' of undefined

Comment: Thanks work fine without the [0]. Before I've find this way to have nextX and nextY: var xData = this.series.xData;
                  var actIndex = $.inArray(this.x, xData);
                  var nextX = actIndex !== xData.length - 1 ? xData[actIndex + 1] : xData[actIndex];
                  var yData = this.series.yData;
                  var yactIndex = $.inArray(this.y, yData);
                  var nextPoint = yactIndex !== yData.length - 1 ? yData[actIndex + 1] : yData[actIndex];

Comment: And you share this with me, because..? :)

Comment: If others have the same problem and want toso the same thing with shared tooltip. But I have to write this here because I can't Answer to my quetion due to my reputation.

Comment: How to get an x value of next point? ;) I tried code from up but it shows me errors from the first comment